# Is using assert_select correct for RSpec controller tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I've been unable to find much documentation or advice on writing good RSpec controller tests. Specifically, should you use Rails' `assert_select` which feels very unlike the RSpec or is there an alternative for it?

Is the example below best practice?

```
describe ArticlesController do
  render_views
  let(:article) { create(:article) }

  describe "show" do
    it "should display the article title" do
      get :show, id: article
      response.should be_success
      assert_select "h1", article.title
    end
  end
end
```

I don't wish to write separate view tests as that's pretty inconvenient.

Comment: Rspec's doc lives here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec . But there is nothing particular concerning your question there

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following code to check the title content:

```
page.should have_selector("h1", :text => article.title)
```

**UPDATE**: As someone noted (with the -1) the answer was wrong, the `page` variable is something set by Capybara after a call to the `visit` method (I was young when I answered :P). So it's something you use in integration tests not in functional tests (controller) as you're trying to do.

**Short answer**: No, it's not correct to use `assert_select` in controller tests (used to check request responses, if variables are set, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but `page` is not defined in the test. This is with rspec-rails 2.8.1 and Rails 3.2.

Comment: Mmmm...do you have require 'spec_helper'?

Comment: I'm a newbie but maybe the page variable is set by visit. Try to replace the get :show line with visit "articles/show/#{article.id}"

Comment: As far as I know `visit` is for use with Webrat or Capybara in integration tests as it is for driving a simulated web browser session. Not something you want to do in controller/functional tests.